# Can I calculate Cohen's $d$ from multiple regression coefficient?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, cohens-d

**Question:** Is it appropriate to calculate Cohen's $d$ (effect size) from the regression coefficient of an independent categorical variable?

**Background:** My regression coefficient represents participation in an intervention (treatment group = 1; comparison group = 0).

My inclination is to simply divide the coefficient by the standard deviation of the dependent variable.

This approach makes conceptual sense to me since this coefficient represents the **average** predicted **difference** in the dependent variable between subjects in the treatment and comparison groups (while all other independent variables are held constant).

Does the application of Cohen's $d$ extend to multiple regression?

Comment: I think you should divide by RMSE instead of the SD. Also, this would give you Hedges g rather than Cohen's d.